# Long query strings return same page on my website

Tags: php, apache, server

Whenever I add `?` with many characters after my website url I get the same page; the url is the same along with the search queries.

`domain.com/anypage/?s=700chars` returns `domain/anypage/?s=700chars` but encoded: spaces become %20.

This is ruining my search queries: instead of showing results it shows the same page.

I tried it on another server and it returns results. To test it I put a working site on the server with a non-working site, and it stopped searching correctly.

I strongly suspects it's the server but why?

Comment: 700 chars shouldn't be a problem. Is it maybe much more? Here are some infos about GET query limits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Comment: Could you show us how you are handling with GET queries ? Show us some code so that we can answer you.

Comment: no , its 700 chars, it does work on other websites which have same wordpress and theme but different server

Comment: @HoloHokkaido what files do you want? I have seen the search.php and search form on my wordpress site , they are correct. my only concern is if it has anything to do with any config on my server